# ¿Mi grid no se actualiza por alguna razon?

Tags: javascript, extjs

`introducir el código aquí`BUENOS DIAS TENGO UN GRID EN EXTJS  QUE NO SE ACTULIZA O MUESTRA LOS DATOS AL INSTANTE ESTO AL  ACTUALIZAR  O CREAR  UN REGISTRO CON UN FORM [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 3. Cosas: 1. Bienvenido a SOes. 2. Escribir en mayúsculas = gritar, esta es una premisa aceptada desde hace muchos años en internet. 3. Lecturas altamente recomendadas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Saludos.

Comment: Hola, varias cosas: las minúsculas mejor, si no se puede interpretar como que estas [gritando](https://desarrolloscreativos.net/2-buenas-razones-para-no-escribir-todo-en-mayusculas/), las imágenes de código tampoco son bien recibidas, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y leas [ask]

Comment: El código va _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de:

```
griddetalle.detalle.removeAll();
griddetalle.detalle.load();
```

Ensaya a utilizar:

```
griddetalle.detalle.reload();
```

Otro consejo es que separes el código de la función de las presentaciones (*views*) utilizando un controlador para ello.